# How to show model title instead on #<Mymodel:0x000000...> in activeadmin dropdown menus?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activeadmin

I've created an association where Project has_many Tasks and Task belongs_to Project.
I've created the form in admin/tasks.rb

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :project
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Now in the edit Task page I hahe a dropdown menu where I can choose the project, but the entry are `#<Project:0x00000...>.` 
How can I customize the entries in the dropdown to show the Project title field instead?

I'm a Rails newbie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Active admin makes use of formtastic, under the hood formtastic loops through your model searching for a method like name, to_s, value, title, that returns a string. 
At the moment you see the data entry itself, if you want formtastic to show the name, make sure you put something like

```
def name
    return self.what_key_you_want_to_use
end
```

in your Project.rb model.

That should let formtastic show the name action instead of the model .to_s!

Comment: Isn't it bad to look into model for data that are presentational by its nature?

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:-

In project.rb (Model) to make ActiveAdmin display properly in select dropdown use alias_attribute.

alias_attribute :name, :project_name (or whatever you named the field in your database)

Answer (score 0):

tldr: You can define or alias `:to_label` on your model to customize the label used:

```
def to_label
  "#{name} - (#{id})"
end

alias_attribute :to_label, :name
```

The library used by Rails: [Formtastic](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/), (or an alternative: [Simple Form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form)) uses the [collection_label_methods](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/blob/833a0783/lib/generators/templates/formtastic.rb#L45-L50) to configure which fields are checked for deriving a label for your model.

Formastic defaults are: `"to_label"`, `"display_name"`, `"full_name"`, `"name"`, `"title"`, `"username"`, `"login"`, `"value"`, `"to_s"`

Simple Form [defaults](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/689f5e63a8a688001427e07934ace3e14131daf2/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb#L90-L91) are: `:to_label`, `:name`, `:title`, `:to_s`

As most of these fields might already be used in your model, `to_label` or `display_name` seems to be the good candidates. I prefer `to_label`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proc like such :

`f.input :your_field, member_label: Proc.new { |p| "#{p.name}"}`