# Trying to add a collection of all of my users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using active admin. I am trying to add a filter to look up by user. Here is my code

```
filter :admin_user, :collection => proc { AdminUser.all }
```

and this is what it is producing in my view.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to map the values for the select:

```
filter :admin_user, :collection => proc { AdminUser.all.map{|u| [u.name, u.id] } }
```

This code implies that the AdminUser model responds to the `.name` method.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but if name method (or attribute) is specified on the model, it should be using that anyway when you pass in the array of model instances per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8429960/178651).